# OpenOffice use .odm programmatically in Java

Tags: java, openoffice.org, uno

I need to do some work on a Master Document (.odm) with the UNO IDL and it's binding to Java.

I want to know if there is a way to access all the documents it's referencing and, if possible, without extracting the content.xml.

What I managed to do so far is to open the document as a XComponent, to open it's XTextDocument interface (and to extract the text belonging to the document but not the one from the included documents). And I'm unable to gather some useful information from that.
Is there an interface that could help? Or some other stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into the ODF Toolkit, since the easier parts are Java-based.

The ODF Toolkit project is currently moving to an Apache incubator project.

The current site is here: http://odftoolkit.org/

The new project is at http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/

On the other hand, extracting the content.xml of the .odm might be a better way to go.  There is probably some XSLT magic you can use to locate the references to the separate parts.

Also, when you open the master document in an OpenOffice.org consumer, doesn't it show clues about how the constituent documents are found?  The one time I messed with this, I noticed that the components had software-generated names that were pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the links, that looks great. Well, extracting the content.xml of the .odm is what we've decided to do for now.
And no, I didn't see any obvious name to help me when I tried.